# Why does a TestMethod has access to internal properties?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, pex

I am very new to testing, and I ran into a particular scenario where a Test Project's Test Method has access to an internal property.  Is this working as designed, or can someone please explain to me why this works?

Snippet from Test Class:

```
/// <summary>This class contains parameterized unit tests for NWatchSystemConfiguration</summary>
    [PexClass(typeof(NWatchSystemConfiguration))]
    [PexAllowedExceptionFromTypeUnderTest(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
    [PexAllowedExceptionFromTypeUnderTest(typeof(ArgumentException), AcceptExceptionSubtypes = true)]
    [TestClass]
    public partial class NWatchSystemConfigurationTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CreateEncryptedPropertyTest()
        {
            const string propertyName = "createdEncryptedProperty";
            const string propertyValue = "testValue";

            const string expected = propertyValue;

            target.CreateProperty(propertyName, propertyValue, true); 

            var actual = target.AppSettings.Settings[propertyName].Value;  // AppSettings is an internal property

            Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }
```

Snippet from class being tested:

```
public class NWatchSystemConfiguration : NWatchConfigurationBase
    {
        internal AppSettingsSection AppSettings;

        // Output emitted for brevity
    }
```

Comment: Search for the InternalsVisibleTo attribute in the assembly that the NWatchSystemConfiguration class exists within.  The test assembly has most likely been marked as being able to see the internals of the product code.

Comment: Look for an `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssemblyName")]` attribute in the tested assembly.

Comment: You guys are correct.  Please answer so I can mark as the answer!

Comment: if they are in two different assemblies you can't access AppSettings from NWatchSystemConfiguration. Maybe you have added [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssemblyName")] to your assemblyinfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you haven't use **[InternalsVisibleTo attribute](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/net-tips-using-internalsvisibleto-attribute-to-help-testing-non-public-methods/)** in your AssembnlyInfo.cs you won't be able to access it. 
Take a look at your assemblyinfo.cs. I think you will find something like `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssemblyName")]` there.